# How to remove ADBannerView in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad, xcode6, adbannerview

I am creating a SpriteKit game with multiple scenes. I want to remove the ad once the users starts to play the actual game, then create another ad when the user transitions to the Gameover scene. Hiding the adbannerview does not work, as it will not reappear once the user loses again.

So how do you remove an AdBannerView?

Comment: Can you provide some code? Can't help much without any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a NSNotification in the GameViewController, something like this:

```
    func hideAdBanner(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("hiding banner")
    adBanner.alpha = 0
    adBanner.hidden = true
}


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideAdBanner:" , name: "hideAdBanner", object: nil)
    }
```

Then call this NSNotification in your scene